# I want to make the image go to the top once the size of the web browser is reduced in flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout, flutter-web

MY code`Class _LandingState extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

```
  body: Center(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              child: Container( 
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/pic.png')
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ),

        ),`
```

after shrinking
[the following image shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7wAq.png)

Comment: You are using Center as the body. everything inside it will be positioned in center.

Comment: i removed the center still dosent work